# How to update a ejs partial in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ejs, partial

I have a file home.ejs which includes one partial user.ejs .When I click on a button I want to render the user.ejs without reloading the home.ejs with the data returned from http post request .

Some like this is happening :

when I get : localhost:3000/home

res.render('Home.ejs', data : data);

Home.ejs rendered with user.ejs and the data .

---

through a form post I again submit one request to post : localhost:3000/home

res.render('User.ejs', data : data)

Now I only want to update the User.ejs and render only this partial .

Any help appreciated .

Comment: You should expose an endpoint for obtaining the user information and get the data using a client-side AJAX request

Comment: If i understood right , you mean to say , I should create one end point some thing like  localhost:3000/home/:user1 and then fetch the data through post request ? Will it re-render only the User.ejs partial ? The complete page won`t reload again with this ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. However I must ask - why exactly a POST request? Also note that fetching an already rendered `User.ejs` partial will be much slower than fetching only the data in a standard service-based architecture.

Comment: No, It would be GET request with new route . I don`t know how can I update only the data in the view without reloading it ? It is possible to only fetch data and update the user.ejs view ?

Comment: Take a look at this article on the basics of REST and SPA (single-page application) to see how you can retrieve only the data from the server as a JSON and update the html page dynamically based on the response: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/